What does "l" stand for in "C'est ce que l'on appelle les marges." ?
Could you give a hand with the sentence "C'est ce que l'on appelle les marges."? What does l stand for in this sentence?
Thanks a lot in advance.

I appreciate your comment.

The l is said to be explétif. Said differently, it is useless on a syntactic point of view and is only present for phonaesthetics reasons.

L' is a relic from the time when on, as a name, required an article. It can be useful for euphony (to avoid an hiatus) or ill-advised (when following a voiced, final l), otherwise it is optional.

It is used for esthetic reasons. To avoid the sound of con.
